# Eclipse can not detect Genymotion emulator nor AVD emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am having this problem with Eclipse which can not detect my Genymotion emulator nor the AVD emulator even though both are running normally and  correctly configured (plugin added succesfully for Genymotion) and worked fine with it before that error happened suddenly.

Error message:

> No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD

What I have tried: I restarted everything (ADT, Genymotion, AVD) and it did not work.

What I want: I want to test Android applications on Genymotion and AVD emulators.

Comment: Heeey, What are you doing there without answering my question ?? :-p

Comment: Run Configurations> Android Applications> Target> Check Always prompt to pick a device.